# MySQL cache of subset queries

Tags: mysql, database, caching, select, query-cache

I am attempting to make a query run on a large database in acceptable time.  I'm looking at optimizing the query itself (e.g. [Clarification of join order for creation of temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728097/clarification-of-join-order-for-creation-of-temporary-tables)), which took me from not being able to complete the query at all (with a 20 hr cap) to completing it but with time that's still not acceptable.

In experimenting, I found the following strange behavior that I'd like to understand:  I want to do the query over a time range of 2 years.  If I try to run it like that directly, then it still will not complete within the 10 min I'm allowing for the test.  If I reduce it to the first 6 months of the range, it will complete pretty quickly.  If I then incrementally re-run the query by adding a couple of months to the range (i.e. run it for 8 months, then 10 months, up to the full 2 yrs), each successive attempt will complete and I can bootstrap my way up to being able to get the full two years that I want.

I suspected that this might be possible due to caching of results by the MySQL server, but that does not seem to match the documentation:

> If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

The key word there seems to be "identical," and the apparent requirement that the queries be identical was reenforced by other reading that I did. ([The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-operation.html) even indicate that the comparison on the query is literal to the point that logically equivalent queries written with "SELECT" vs. "select" would not match.)  In my case, each subsequent query contains the full range of the previous query, but no two of them are identical.

Additionally, the tables are updated overnight.  So at the end of the day yesterday we had the full, 2-yr query running in 19 sec when, presumably, it was cached since we had by that point obtained the full result at least once.  Today we cannot make the query run anymore, which would seem to be consistent with the cache having been invalidated when the table was updated last night.

So the questions: Is there some special case that allows the server to cache in this case?  If yes, where is that documented?  If not, any suggestion on what else would lead to this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did some experimentation, including checking the effect from the system noted in the answer by @Solarflare. In our case, we concluded that the apparent caching was real, but it had nothing to do with MySQL at all. It was instead caused by the Linux disk cache. We were able to verify this in our case by manually flushing that cache after and before getting a result and comparing times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a cache that optimizes (general) access to the harddrive. It is actually a very important part of every storage based database system, because reading data from (or writing e.g. temporary data to) the harddrive is usually the most relevant bottleneck for most queries.

For InnoDB, this is called the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html):

> InnoDB maintains a storage area called the buffer pool for caching data and indexes in memory. Knowing how the InnoDB buffer pool works, and taking advantage of it to keep frequently accessed data in memory, is an important aspect of MySQL tuning. For information about how the InnoDB buffer pool works, see InnoDB Buffer Pool LRU Algorithm.
>
> You can configure the various aspects of the InnoDB buffer pool to improve performance.
>
> - Ideally, you set the size of the buffer pool to as large a value as practical, leaving enough memory for other processes on the server to run without excessive paging. **The larger the buffer pool, the more InnoDB acts like an in-memory database, reading data from disk once and then accessing the data from memory during subsequent reads.** See Section 15.6.3.2, “Configuring InnoDB Buffer Pool Size”.

There can be (and have been) written books about the [buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-performance-buffer-pool.html), how it works and how to [optimize it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html), so I will stop there and just leave you with this keyword and refer you to the documentation.

Basically, your subsequent reads add data to the cache that can be reused until it has been replaced by other data (which in your case has happened the next day). Since (for MySQL) this can be any read of the involved tables and doesn't have to be your maybe complicated query, it might make the "prefetching" easier for you.

Although the following comes with a disclaimer because it obviously can have a negative impact on your server if you change your configuration: the default MySQL configuration is very (very) conservative, and e.g. the [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) system setting is way too low for most servers younger than 15 years, so maybe have a look at your configuration (or let your system administrator check it).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After some experimentation, in our case it appears to have been file system caching at the level of the operating system and nothing to do with MySQL at all.